# How to find 2 columns contain partial similar string

Tags: sql, string, plsql

I have 2 columns (Location and Name) and I need to find out whether the two have similar strings.
I am trying to get a new column that returns 1 if there is a match and 0 if there's no match at all.
Here's an example of my data and the column I need:

```
|   Location   |     Name     | Result  |
|:-----------: |:------------:|:-------:|
| Sherman Oaks | Oaks         | 1       | 
|Beverly drive | Sherman way  | 0       |             
|Hollywood Blvd| Hollywood    | 1       |
|  3rd Street  |    Main      | 0       |
|   Ventura    |   Park Ave   | 0       |
| Palm Springs |     Null     | 0       |
```

Comment: Hi - 1) please don't use images in your questions, used editable text so someone can copy it if they want to try out a solution 2) What's your definition of "similar" - is it case sensitive, are you only matching words or are you matching strings? How long do strings need to be in order for there to be a match, etc?

Answer (score 0):

With sample data you posted and desired result, this might be one option: check whether `location` exists in `name` or vice versa. If so, result = `1`.

Note, though, that there might be false positives or even false negatives; to avoid them, try to present precise rules which lead to desired result.

```
SQL> select location, name,
  2    case when instr(location, name) > 0 or
  3              instr(name, location) > 0
  4         then 1
  5         else 0
  6    end result
  7  from test;

LOCATION             NAME            RESULT
-------------------- ----------- ----------
Sherman Oaks         Oaks                 1
Beverly drive        Sherman way          0
Hollywood Blvd       Hollywood            1
3rd Street           Main                 0
Ventura              Park Ave             0
Palm Springs                              0
Sherman Oaksland     Oaks                 1 -> false positive? (substring match)
Sherman Way          way                  0 -> false negative? (case sensitivity)

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```